# Keras in R: looking for function equivalent to plot_model in Python

Tags: r, keras, visualization

In Python, Keras has a convenient function `plot_model` which visualises the architecture of your model -- an example included below. I'm looking for an equivalent function in R that works with the `keras` library (not `kerasR`). If you have any suggestions on how to generate such image in R, I'd love to hear from you.

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: There is a corresponding (as of now open) issue in rstudio/keras: https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/408

Comment: Is there a solution now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the latest on the issue: https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/325.

[Andrie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/602276/andrie) implemented a `plot_model()` function similar to Python's `keras::plot_model()`. Link to the documentation: https://andrie.github.io/deepviz/index.html.